# Vuejs- stop clearing data properties after routing back to previous component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I'm implementing a simple subscription app.

1- At the first step of subscription i get phone and nick name :

template :

```
<input type="phone" v-model="phone" class="form-control" placeholder=" 09128684821">
```

script :

```
data() {
  return {
    phone:''
  };
},
```

2- next step is OTP (one time password) that user receive in SMS.

**Here's the problem**: when the user go back to modify his phone number in the previous component, the old phone number is removed and he must enter the phone number again.(*BAD UX*)

what should i do to stop clearing phone number after routing back to previous it's component?

Comment: You could use Vuex to store your state and check if a phone number exists when the component is loaded. Another option would be to wrap your `router-view` within a `keep-alive` element.

Comment: cant we solve it without Vuex ? ex: using a watcher on phone property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), cookies, etc. to store the phone number.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/digitaldrifter/3m9yr470/) demonstrating localStorage and vue router.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.component('phone-number', {
  template: `<div>
  <label>Phone Number</label>
  <input v-model="phoneNumber">
  <router-link to="/otp">Next</router-link>
  </div>`,
  data: () => ({ phoneNumber: null }),
  watch: {
    phoneNumber: {
      handler: function (value) {
        localStorage.setItem('phone-number', value)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.phoneNumber = localStorage.getItem('phone-number')
  }
})

Vue.component('one-time-password', {
  template: `<div>
  <label>One Time Password</label>
  <input v-model="otp">
  <router-link to="/">Back</router-link>
  </div>`,
  data: () => ({ otp: null })
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      component: {
        template: '<phone-number/>'
      },
      path: '/'
    },
    {
      component: {
        template: '<one-time-password/>'
      },
      path: '/otp'
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
})
```

Comment: for the first time that user visit the page, this code return null, because localStorage has not set. i used local storage for setting but for getting the value i just used v-model and data property.

Comment: That is the expected value for a user's first visit. As they enter their phone number it's stored and retrieved on subsequent visits.

Comment: i can't make phone a computed property because i'm using it in another computed property for validation.

Comment: I updated both the answer and the jsfiddle example. It uses a watcher now: http://jsfiddle.net/digitaldrifter/3m9yr470/

Comment: I solved it in my data property: `phone: localStorage.getItem('phone')`